# I need tips on reforming my question

Tags: discussion

This is the problematic question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696904/how-can-i-install-web-service-on-server

It got -8 votes, highest number of downvotes i ever saw in this site. It probably means that my question was really really bad, one of the worst ever.

I am asking for help and tips about proper forming of question. I kinda need 15+ reputation to be able to upvote good answers.
Thanks!

Comment: Your question being **far** from the worst one ever, you should really read this [FAQ].

Comment: In your question you are describing totally vague what you want. And you don't show what you already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: It is a bad question, yes. It's almost the equivalent of asking "I want to build a thing, that needs to do stuff and work on Android too. How can I do that?". Now you try answering that one. ;) Perhaps have a read through this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx Don't get too upset about it though. Just learn and improve.

Comment: If you think -8 is bad, then what do you call [a post with a score of -133](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53297/186381)?

Comment: @Servy A challenge?

Comment: @Bart Just hoping to add some perspective.  Just imagine how much worse it could be,  "Don't feel too bad, it's just -8."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question:

> I need to make web service with some functions and use those functions later in my program. How can i make C# web service on random free hosting server and access it from my program?
>
> Also, can i use that same web service made in c# for android applications?

Is overly broad.  Let's break it down:

> "I need to make web service with some functions."

Great. Have you searched on the internet for [building web services in C#](https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=create+webservice+C#&oq=create+webservice+C#&gs_l=hp.3..0i10l4.74.3728.0.4065.30.23.5.0.0.0.134.1700.19j4.23.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.1slRRZbid_M&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.dmQ&fp=8be17aaf92ef5992&biw=1920&bih=946)?

If so, you're hopefully at the point where you've created this web service. Are you?

Next:

> How can i make C# web service on random free hosting server

First, focus on making a web service. Have you done that? Have you accessed it locally?

Once you've done that, then [try to find a hosting service](https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=C#+hosting+service&oq=C#+hosting+service&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l4.87.2048.0.2952.18.15.0.3.3.0.140.1038.14j1.15.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.v48GA0hEH80&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.dmQ&fp=8be17aaf92ef5992&biw=1920&bih=946).  Narrow it down.  Find the hosting provider you want to use, and try to install your newly created web  service on it.

Once you've done that, then you probably want to look up how to [access a Third Party API from Android](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=connect+to+REST+API+through+android&oq=connect+to+REST+API+through+android&gs_l=hp.3...6285.6878.1.7068.5.5.0.0.0.0.102.331.4j1.5.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.pcoh4haKCLY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.dmQ&fp=8be17aaf92ef5992&biw=1920&bih=946).

Your problem space is way too big. Your question is essentially saying:

> I need to build a web service in C#. I don't know how. Please give me an example of how to create a web service in C#.  Now, how do I install that web service on {every hosting provider, ever}?  Now that I've done that, how do I access that webservice from android?

There's no way to salvage that question short of completely re-writing it to be a specific question about a specific problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

> It got -8 votes, highest number of downvotes i ever saw in this site. It probably means that my question was really really bad, one of the worst ever.

Very far from the worst question ever. Still, you should read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) to make sur you understand how it works around here.

From your question I can see that

- You didn't show that you tried to solve your problem before comming here.
- You didn't show what you have tried so far.
- The question is very vague and unlikely to get a good clear answer.

All the tools you need to write a good question are there. You just need to use them.

---

Now about this part.

> I am asking for help and tips about proper forming of question. I kinda need 15+ reputation to be able to upvote good answers. Thanks!

Please don't ask questions just so that you can reach 15rep. You will get these points in time. Asking a question simply to get rep will probably result in posting a *poor quality* question and therefore what happened to your previous question will happen on these.